# Where and how to correct the "INVALID IDENTITY CREDENTIANLS " while running ./stack.sh?

Tags: devstack

I have written this in my envirn var file and sourced it...

```
export OS_USERNAME=admin
export OS_PASSWORD=passwrd
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://localhost:5000/v2.0/
```

its still giving me the same error... can anyone elaborate what to do with the token thing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't set any environ variables before running stack.sh.Devstack comes with its own identity credentials that creates admin and demo users.